# Images being inverted on its own using CarrierWave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-storage, carrierwave, fog

So i'm using CarrierWave together with Google Cloud Storage.

Here's my `uploader`

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick    
  process :auto_orient

  if Rails.env.production?
    storage :fog
  else
    storage :file
  end

  def auto_orient
    manipulate! do |image|
      image.tap(&:auto_orient)
    end
  end

  #not the whole chunk of code, just what i thought would be relevant
end
```

So anyway, images are being stored on Google Cloud Storage as mentioned. However, ***some*** of the images are being rotated, 90deg or 180deg and i cannot figure out why?

There's little documentation regarding this issue, it is not occurring with all the photos, and the only thing i would find that was supposed to help would be the `auto_orient` portion from [here](https://makandracards.com/makandra/12323-carrierwave-auto-rotate-tagged-jpegs).

Also, when i go onto my google cloud storage and look at the actual photos being uploaded, they appear upright and proper. Does anyone have any idea what is going on with the photos?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have the same issue in s3.

Comment: Unfortunately no, i did not... I did a manual work around it (reuploading a rotated photo)

Comment: So for me, the photos are actually being shown correctly when viewed in mobile, but on desktop they are sideways.

Comment: I can't remember if mine was showing correctly on different platforms or not. But unfortunately i didn't find a solution. So sorry. All the best to finding a solution! And if you do feel free to post your answer here, i'll gladly approve it!

Comment: Actually, it looks like auto_orient is working for me. Just not retroactively. So the old photos have to be reuploaded.

Comment: You can submit that as an answer here and i will accept it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42862741/photos-uploaded-by-mobile-with-carreirwave-dropzone-are-rotated-correctly-in-s3

Comment: Ah okay. It didn't occur to me that auto_orient was working for me too and just not retroactively to be honest. But that's good to know. Thanks mate! I'll upload it there. Cheers :)