# Photos uploaded by mobile with carreirwave/dropzone are rotated correctly in s3 but are showing up sideways on my webapp

Tags: amazon-s3, carrierwave, dropzone.js

When a User uploads photos with a mobile phone using Carrierwave/Dropzone the photos will sometimes be sideways in the preview, however the photos are being saved in s3 with the correct rotation. However, despite being saved in s3 with the correct rotation, when they are then shown on the web app, they are again being shown sideways. Very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code to get it working

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick    
  process :auto_orient

  def auto_orient
    manipulate! do |image|
      image.tap(&:auto_orient)
    end
  end

end
```

Side note: `auto_orient` does not work retroactively, images need to be re-uploaded for them to have the proper orientation.